# Rails is redirectin to a site i didnt choose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I followed the tutorial from railscast about authentication. Because I have two models that should be authenticated I changed the session create code a little bit:

```
 def create
   if User.find_by_username(params[:username]) != nil
     user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
     if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
       session[:user_id] = user.id
       redirect_to root_path, notice: "Eingeloged als User"
     end
   elsif Admin.find_by_username(params[:username]) != nil
     admin = Admin.find_by_username(params[:username])
     if admin && admin.authenticate(params[:password])
       session[:user_id] = admin.id
       redirect_to adminpage_index_path, notice: "Eingeloged als Admin"
     end
   else   
     flash[:error] = "Benutzername oder Password ist falsch"
     render 'new'
   end
 end
```

If I login as user it works, and when I type in a false password it also works. But somehow when I want to login as admin I get the error:

```
Template is missing
Missing template sessions/create
```

I don't know why I get this error! I mean where does my code say that it should redirect to session create ? Thanks

My routes:

```
get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'

resources :users
resources :sessions
```

Comment: you don't - but what if you provide a password that doesn't match? It's going to try and render the action.

Comment: Can You Post Your Routes

Comment: But i mean i have this else loop `render new`

Comment: @Aditya i added my routes! Maybe if the username is correct but the password invalid it redirects to create?

Comment: Have added an answer. Maybe the authentication is missing.. You Can debug into the loops..

Comment: By the way: You shouldn't create two models for users. Add `role`to `User` model and throw away the `Admin` model. Also you should put the authentification method in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the logic in your controller action:

```
if admin && admin.authenticate(params[:password])
  session[:user_id] = admin.id
  redirect_to adminpage_index_path, notice: "Eingeloged als Admin"
end
```

If you have provided a valid username and an invalid password, what is going to happen?

You're not going to get into that `if` statement - you're going to continue through the controller action, fall out the bottom, and the default behaviour in Rails is to render a view at the end of an action if no other behaviour is requested. Hence it's trying to render the create view for your create action - which doesn't exist.

You need to handle the invalid-password case for both users and admins.

Also, why are you calling `find_by_username` twice for both users and admins?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the else part in Admin authentication..
It should be,

```
def create
   if User.find_by_username(params[:username]) != nil
     user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
     if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
       session[:user_id] = user.id
       redirect_to root_path, notice: "Eingeloged als User"
     else
       redirect_to root_path, notice: "Your Notice"
     end
   elsif Admin.find_by_username(params[:username]) != nil
     admin = Admin.find_by_username(params[:username])
     if admin && admin.authenticate(params[:password])
       session[:user_id] = admin.id
       redirect_to adminpage_index_path, notice: "Eingeloged als Admin"
     else
       redirect_to root_path, notice: "Your Notice"
     end
   else   
     flash[:error] = "Benutzername oder Password ist falsch"
     render 'new'
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the faulty line is the `redirect_to adminpage_index_path, notice: "Eingeloged als Admin"` . It may help if you post your routes (run `rake routes` from your terminal). If it's saying the template is missing though, likely you don't have an index.html.erb in your app/views/adminpages/ folder? Is there a file there? (Also make sure you have the appropriate app/contollers/adminpages_controller and appropriate `index` action.

Comment: adminpage_index_path exists and works! I mean my error says Template is missing
Missing template sessions/create

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't see the 'sessions/create' after Missing Template before